# @ManyToOne hibernate mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

How to prevent record insertion in `@ManyToOne` hibernate mapping. Their Parent table have no record. We tried to insert record without parent table primary key and still the record was inserted into child table

```js
Domain class

Department Table(Parent)

@Table(name = "Department")
@Entity
public class Department {
  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "g1", strategy = "increment")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "g1")
  private int deptno;
  private String deptname;
  private String depthead;
  public Department() {
    System.out.println("Department:0-param constuctor");
  }
  public int getDeptno() {
    return deptno;
  }
  public void setDeptno(int deptno) {
    this.deptno = deptno;
  }
  public String getDeptname() {
    return deptname;
  }
  public void setDeptname(String deptname) {
    this.deptname = deptname;
  }
  public String getDepthead() {
    return depthead;
  }
  public void setDepthead(String depthead) {
    this.depthead = depthead;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Department [deptno=" + deptno + ", deptname=" + deptname +
      ", depthead=" + depthead + "]";
  }
}



Emplyee table(child)

@Table(name = "EmpDetails")
@Entity
public class EmpDetails {
  @Id
  private int eno;
  private String ename;
  private double salary;
  @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Department.class,
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "deptno", referencedColumnName = "deptno")
  private Department dept;
  public EmpDetails() {
    System.out.println("EmpDetails:0-param constructor");
  }
  public int getEno() {
    return eno;
  }
  public void setEno(int eno) {
    this.eno = eno;
  }
  public String getEname() {
    return ename;
  }
  public void setEname(String ename) {
    this.ename = ename;
  }
  public double getSalary() {
    return salary;
  }
  public void setSalary(double salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
  }
  public Department getDept() {
    return dept;
  }
  public void setDept(Department dept) {
    this.dept = dept;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "EmpDetails [eno=" + eno + ", ename=" + ename + ", salary=" +
      salary + "]";
  }
}
```

```js
DAO

@Override
public void addEmployeesWithDept() {
  // get Session
  Session ses = HibernateUtil.getSession();
  // create Department (parent) 
  //Department dept=new Department();
  //dept.setDeptname("Accounts");
  //dept.setDepthead("Jhon");

  //create Employees(childs)
  EmpDetails emp1 = new EmpDetails();
  emp1.setEno(107);
  emp1.setEname("raja");
  emp1.setSalary(9000);

  EmpDetails emp2 = new EmpDetails();
  emp2.setEno(108);
  emp2.setEname("ravi");
  emp2.setSalary(8000);

  // set childs to parent
  //emp1.setDept(); emp2.setDept();
  //Save objs

  Transaction tx = null;
  try {
    tx = ses.beginTransaction();
    ses.save(emp1);
    ses.save(emp2);
    tx.commit();
    System.out.println(" Employees(childs) and associated parent objs are saved");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    tx.rollback();
  }
}
```

```js
Main Method 
public static void main(String[] args) {
   // Get DAO
  M2ODAO dao=M2ODAOFactory.getDAOInstance();
  //perform persitence operations
    dao.addEmployeesWithDept();
  
  //Close objs
  HibernateUtil.closeSession();
  HibernateUtil.closeSessionFactory();
 }//main
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find the below classes.
Main change: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#nullable()
Specify below line: **nullable = false**

```
@JoinColumn(name = "deptno", referencedColumnName = "deptno", nullable = false)
```

which makes deptNo column as not null. Additionally specify deptNo as not null column so it avoids saving empdetails without dept number.

Or you can use: [@NotNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) on that field.

```
@NotNull
private Deparment dept;
```

Your model classes

```
Domain class

Department Table(Parent)

@Table(name = "Department")
@Entity
public class Department {
  @Id
  @GenericGenerator(name = "g1", strategy = "increment")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "g1")
  private int deptno;
  private String deptname;
  private String depthead;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "department")
  private List<EmpDetails> empDetails = new ArrayList<EmpDetails>();

  public Department() {
    System.out.println("Department:0-param constuctor");
  }
  public int getDeptno() {
    return deptno;
  }
  public void setDeptno(int deptno) {
    this.deptno = deptno;
  }
  public String getDeptname() {
    return deptname;
  }
  public void setDeptname(String deptname) {
    this.deptname = deptname;
  }
  public String getDepthead() {
    return depthead;
  }
  public void setDepthead(String depthead) {
    this.depthead = depthead;
  }


public List<EmpDetails> getEmpDetails() {
    return empDetails;
}


public void setEmpDetails(List<EmpDetails> empDetails) {
    this.empDetails = empDetails;
}

@Transient
public void addRoomAndBed(EmpDetails empDetails) {
    if (getEmpDetails() == null) {
        setRoomAndBeds(new ArrayList<EmpDetails>());
    }
    getEmpDetails().add(empDetails);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return "Department [deptno=" + deptno + ", deptname=" + deptname +
  ", depthead=" + depthead + "]";
}
}



Emplyee table(child)

@Table(name = "EmpDetails")
@Entity
public class EmpDetails {
@Id
private int eno;
private String ename;
private double salary;
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Department.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "deptno", referencedColumnName = "deptno", nullable = false)
private Department dept;
public EmpDetails() {
System.out.println("EmpDetails:0-param constructor");
}
public int getEno() {
return eno;
}
public void setEno(int eno) {
this.eno = eno;
}
public String getEname() {
return ename;
}
public void setEname(String ename) {
this.ename = ename;
}
public double getSalary() {
return salary;
}
public void setSalary(double salary) {
this.salary = salary;
}
public Department getDept() {
return dept;
}
public void setDept(Department dept) {
this.dept = dept;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
return "EmpDetails [eno=" + eno + ", ename=" + ename + ", salary=" +
  salary + "]";
}
}
```